# How to check if cell value is time - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I m trying to check if cell value it time without luck.

I use `IsDate(cell.value)` but always get `False`.
column format is `Time`

Data structure:

[image]

Comment: Times are doubles, not dates.

Comment: You can also use `?typename(cell.value)` in Immediate Window to determine cell's datatype.

Comment: You could look at its `.NumberFormat` returning `h:mm` for example?

Answer (score 1):

You can use：

```
isdate(format(now(),"yyyy-mm-dd ") & "yourtime")
```

The same to isdate.

```
?isdate(format(now(),"yyyy-mm-dd ") & "12:12:13")

True

?isdate(format(now(),"yyyy-mm-dd ") & "32:12:13")

False
```

[image]